# AVERAGE in SQL query is giving different result from AVERAGEX in DAX

Tags: oracle, dax, ssas-tabular

I have the following SQL query :

```
SELECT
AVG(
nvl("PROP_TxMarge",0) * ((nvl("PROP_MtDemandeFin",0) - ( nvl("ENV_MontantInitial",0) - nvl("ENV_MontantDisponible",0) ) ) * nvl("POOLFIN_Pct",0))
)
FROM myTable
```

and this is the KPI syntax I am using :

```
KPIFormula := AVERAGEX('myTable',

 

[PROP_TxMarge] *

(

( [PROP_MtDemandeFin]

- ( [ENV_MontantInitial]

- [ENV_MontantDisponible] ))

* [POOLFIN_Pct]

)

)
```

I am having different results.

Comment: Sample data and the two results for that data might be helpful. But do you have null values? The Oracle version is handling that with `nvl()`. [The DAX docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/averagex-function-dax) say "You cannot include non-numeric or null cells." I'm not familiar with DAX but I read that as maybe saying nulls are silently excluded which might affect the mean calculation. If you change the Oracle version to *exclude* the rows where any of those columns are null, do you then get the same result?

Comment: @AlexPoole I do have NULL values so should I replace them in DAX by zero ?

Comment: That's what you're doing in the Oracle version so... maybe, but I don't really know. (And don't know how to do it in DAX; IF and ISBLANK maybe?) Excluding the nulls from Oracle might indicate if that is actually the issue.

Comment: Try `COALESCE( [col], 0)` to replace blanks with 0. https://dax.guide/coalesce/